# Text display based on condition in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, react-redux, operators

im a new to React

Im trying to display a basic text after i make login based on condition in component of react redux but no matter what, the text shows every time

The login function works fine and i get the name of user after i press on Login Button.

Code of the component:

```
import React from 'react'

import { doSignInAsync, selectUsername,} from '../slicers/authSlice'

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const Authentication = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const username = useSelector(selectUsername)

  return (
    <div>
     
      {username && <div> Hello: {username} </div>}
      
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(doSignInAsync())}>Login</button>

    </div>

  )
}

export default Authentication
```

But i want to get "Hello Michael" only after i make a login (press on a button)

For now "Hello" appears all the time even if i am don't press on a button, and after it turns to "Hello Michael"

What did i make wrong?

Comment: By your admission of incorrect initial state in a [comment](/questions/76613979/text-display-based-on-condition-in-react-js#comment135088007_76614396) I'm voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

## what's going on

`{username && <div> Hello: {username} </div>}` will render any time `username` is truthy.
There is nothing in here that cares about the state of the login button, and `useSelector(selectUsername)` is returning something truthy even before the user has clicked 'login'.

## idea to fix it?

Add some state tracking the state of the login button and make the div's condition also rely upon that.

```js
const Authentication = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const username = useSelector(selectUsername);
  // 
  const [loginClicked,setLoginClicked] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <div>
      //          
      {(username && loginClicked) && <div> Hello: {username} </div>}
      //               
      <button onClick={()=>setLoginClicked(true)}>Login</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I dit exactly as you said, but it still remains the same :/

Comment: I'm sorry Michael. Pre-coffee me made some mistakes there. I've updated my answer. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Actually it was my bad, i didnt pay attention that initial state of username in slicer was  like "  " instead of "", that was source of the problem, my code works fine after i changed that, but anyways thank you so much for ur help !! :)